# How to read from TCP and write to stdout?

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

I'm failing to get a simple scalaz-stream example running, reading from TCP and writing to std out.

```
val src = tcp.reads(1024)
val addr = new InetSocketAddress(12345)
val p = tcp.server(addr, concurrentRequests = 1) {
  src ++ tcp.lift(io.stdOutLines)
}
p.run.run
```

It just sits there, not printing anything.

I've also tried various arrangements using `to`, always with the `tcp.lift` incantation to get a `Process[Connection, A]`, including

```
tcp.server(addr, concurrentRequests = 1)(src) map (_ to tcp.lift(io.stdOutLines))
```

which doesn't even compile.

Do I need to `wye` the source and print streams together? An example I found on the [original pull request](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/pull/250) for `tcp` replacing `nio` seemed to indicate this, but `wye` no longer appears to exist on `Process`, so confusion reigns unfortunately.

---

**Edit** it turns out that in addition to the type problems explained by Paul, you also need to run the inner processes "manually", for example by doing `p.map(_.run.run).run.run`. I don't suppose that's the idiomatic way to do this, but it does work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass `src` through the sink to actually write anything. I think this should do it:

```
import scalaz.stream.{io,tcp,text}
import scalaz.stream.tcp.syntax._

val p = tcp.server(addr, concurrentRequests = 1) { 
  tcp.reads(1024).pipe(text.utf8Decode) through tcp.lift(io.stdOutLines) 
}
p.run.run
```

The expression `src ++ tcp.lift(io.stdOutLines)` should really be a type error. The type of `tcp.reads(1024)` is `Process[Connection,ByteVector]`, and the type of `tcp.lift(io.stdOutLines)` is `Process[Connection, String => Task[Unit]]`. Appending those two processes does not make sense, and the only reason it typechecks is due to the covariance of `Process[+F[_],+O]`. Scala is "helpfully" inferring `Any` when you append two processes with unrelated output types.

A future release of scalaz-stream may add a constraint on `++` and other functions that exploit covariance to make sure the least upper bound that gets computed isn't something useless like `Any` or `Serializable`. This would go a long way to preventing mistakes like this. In the meantime, make sure you understand the types of all the functions you are working with, what they do, and how you are sticking them together.

Comment: Using sbt wart-remover would probably catch that Any inference.

Comment: Do you mean `through io.stdOutLines`, without the `tcp.lift`? Still doesn't seem to be pulling anything off the stream though.

Comment: Ok - with the `tcp.lift` removed, this does work, but note that you have to `p.map(_.run.run).run.run` to get the inner processes to run.